# How to center menu items without the center tag?

Tags: html, css

I found this **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cam/9cNbE/)** and it does what I need with the full width drop down.

**Question:** 
I am trying to get the buttons exactly in the middle and centered with this fill width drop down menu. For some reason when I use the html `<center>` tag is does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //variable where currentAnchor is stored
    var currentSection = 0;
    // hides the submenu as soon as the DOM is ready
    $('#submenu').hide();
    // toggles the submenu on clicking the noted link  
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        
        // remove active class
        $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
        // add active class
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        //hide all submenus
        $('#hidden>ul').hide();
        
        //show one particular menu
        $(href).show();

        
        //logic for hiding and showing submenu
        if(currentSection == 0){
            $('#submenu').slideToggle(200);
            currentSection = href;
        } else if(currentSection == href){
             $('#submenu').slideToggle(200);
             currentSection = 0;    
        } else{
            currentSection = href;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #e45740;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#submenu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #555;
    color: #FFF;
}
#submenu #hidden {
}

* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="submenu" style="display:none;">
   <div id="hidden">
        <ul id="one">
            <li>One</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="two">
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="three">
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and include it **in the question itself** instead.

Comment: `<center>` was superseded by CSS over two decades ago.

Comment: Check text-align css property. It will work, in your case.

Comment: Take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @JermainNewman — You didn't post it on stackoverflow. You posted a link to it. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the below css To make buttons in center

```
#menu{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

I hope it works...

Comment: and its a timed thing... The site says i have to wait a certain amount of time before awarding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML structure is the same as the fiddle link provided you only need to add `text-align:center;` to your ul like so:

```
#menu {
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: i clicked it and it went to 0. Does that mean I can vote?